# Show Label on Map in Open Layers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am working on a process to show location on the map along with its label. I have figured out the way to show the marker location but not the  but I cannot figure out the way to show the label.

Here is my code:

```
var positionFeature = new ol.Feature();
positionFeature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 6,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#3399CC'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#fff',
            width: 2
        })
    })
}));
var labelFeature = new ol.Feature();
labelFeature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
    text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: '14px Calibri,sans-serif',
        overflow: true,
        text: item.item.val.NAME,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: "#000",
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#fff',
            width: 3,
        }),
    }),
}))

Geocoordinates = ol.proj.fromLonLat([it.LONG, it.LAT]);

positionFeature.setGeometry(Geocoordinates ?
    new ol.geom.Point(Geocoordinates) : null);
view.animate({
    center: Geocoordinates,
    duration: 200,
    zoom: 10                        
});
```

Comment: A style can contain both image and text, so you could do that using just one feature.  If you have two features you must set the geometry on both (and they must be added to your layer source).